# Cancelling the task of a URLSession.AsyncBytes doesn't seem to work

Tags: swift, async-await, request, cancellation

I want to download a large file, knowing the number of bytes transferred, and be able to cancel the download if necessary.

I know that this can be done having a `URLSessionDownloadTask` and conforming to the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, but I wanted to achieve it through an `async/await` mechanism, so I used `URLSession.shared.bytes(from: url)` and then a for-await-in loop to handle each byte.

The issue comes when trying to cancel the ongoing task, as even though the `URLSession.AsyncBytes`'s `Task` has been cancelled, the for-await-in loop keeps processing bytes, so I'm assuming that the download is still ongoing.

I've tested it with this piece of code in a playground.

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/large_file.zip")!
        
    let (asyncBytes, _) = try await URLSession.shared.bytes(from: url)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        asyncBytes.task.cancel()
    }

    var data = Data()
    
    for try await byte in asyncBytes {
        
        data.append(byte)
        print(data.count)
    }
```

I would have expected that, as soon as the task is cancelled, the download would have been stopped and, therefore, the for-await-in would stop processing bytes.

What am I missing here? Can these tasks not be effectively cancelled?

Comment: “I've tested it with this piece of code in a playground.” … I would suggest testing in an app, not a playground. Perhaps even a release build. A playground is a very slow environment and fetching byte-by-byte can easily get backlogged, and I wouldn’t be at all surprised to see some latency before the async sequence registers the cancelation. This should be diminished in a real app.

Comment: As an unrelated aside, but I might advise against mixing GCD with `async`-`await`. E.g., I might lean towards `Task { try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)); asyncBytes.task.cancel() }` instead of GCD’s `asyncAfter`.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Task.checkCancellation()` to the loop?

Comment: @Rob – I've tested it in an App (both on the Simulator and Device) and it still doesn't work. I've removed the `asyncAfter`, too, and cancelled it through a button.

Comment: @carlynorama – I have. It doesn't seem to have any effect, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canceling a `URLSessionDataTask` works fine with `AsyncBytes`. That having been said, even if the `URLSessionDataTask` is canceled, the `AsyncBytes` will continue to iterate through the bytes received prior to cancelation. But the data task *does* stop.

Consider `experiment1`:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let url: URL = …
    private let session: URLSession = …
    private var cancelButtonTapped = false
    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    @Published var bytesBeforeCancel = 0
    @Published var bytesAfterCancel = 0

    func experiment1() async throws {
        let (asyncBytes, _) = try await session.bytes(from: url)
        dataTask = asyncBytes.task

        var data = Data()

        for try await byte in asyncBytes {
            if cancelButtonTapped {
                bytesAfterCancel += 1
            } else {
                bytesBeforeCancel += 1
            }
            data.append(byte)
        }
    }

    func cancel() {
        dataTask?.cancel()
        cancelButtonTapped = true
    }
}
```

So, I canceled after 1 second (at which point I had iterated through 2,022 bytes), and it continues to iterate through the remaining 14,204 bytes that had been received prior to the cancelation of the `URLSessionDataTask`. But the download *does* stop successfully. (In my example, the actual asset being downloaded was 74mb.) When using `URLSession`, the data comes in packets, so it takes `AsyncBytes` a little time to get through everything that was actually received before the `URLSession` request was canceled.

[image]

---

You might consider canceling the Swift concurrency `Task`, rather than the `URLSessionDataTask`. (I really wish they did not use the same word, “task”, to refer to entirely different concepts!)

Consider `experiment2`:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let url: URL = …
    private let session: URLSession = …
    private var cancelButtonTapped = false
    private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

    @Published var bytesBeforeCancel = 0
    @Published var bytesAfterCancel = 0

    func experiment2() async throws {
        task = Task { try await download() }
        try await task?.value
    }

    func cancel() {
        task?.cancel()
        cancelButtonTapped = true
    }

    func download() async throws {
        let (asyncBytes, _) = try await session.bytes(from: url)

        var data = Data()

        for try await byte in asyncBytes {
            try Task.checkCancellation()

            if cancelButtonTapped {        // this whole `if` statement is no longer needed, but I've kept it here for comparison to the previous example
                bytesAfterCancel += 1
            } else {
                bytesBeforeCancel += 1
            }

            data.append(byte)
        }
    }
}
```

Without the `try Task.checkCancellation()` line, the behavior is almost the same as in `experiment1`. The cancelation of the `Task` with the `AsyncBytes` will result in the cancelation of the underlying `URLSessionDataTask` (but the sequence will continue to iterate through the bytes in the packets that were successfully received prior to cancelation). But with `try Task.checkCancellation()`, it will exit as soon as the `Task` is canceled.

[image]

Comment: I failed to check my code against a bigger file and fuzzed on it being a URLSessionDataTask and not a concurrency Task. This was great and very helpful. Thank you. I was going to try to learn about HTTP and Instruments today to start checking things, but you know, I could have just used a bigger file :)

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I was expecting it to immediately stop, as with a `URLSessionDownloadTask`, but I just needed to be a little bit more patient! I just tested it with the Playground code and it does work as you said. Oh, well. Now we know. Thanks a lot for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Read Rob's answer, but the iterator code and and the partial download code are still handy so I'm leaving this answer with corrections.

Okay so I spent some time on this because I'm about to try to write my own cancellable url stream object. <strike>and it appears that `asyncBytes.task.cancel()` is more along the lines of URLSession's `finishTasksAndInvalidate()` than `invalidateAndCancel()`.</strike> Since you are pointing your streaming task at a file that isn't really that large the `URLSessionDataTask` had already gotten the bytes in the buffer.

You can see this when you change up the function a bit (see Rob's example as well):

```swift
    func test_funcCondition(timeOut:TimeInterval, url:URL, session:URLSession) async throws {
             
        let (asyncBytes, _) = try await session.bytes(from: url)
    
        let deadLine = Date.now + timeOut
        var data = Data()
    
       func someConditionCheck(_ deadline:Date) -> Bool {
            Date.now > deadLine
        }
        
        for try await byte in asyncBytes {   
            if someConditionCheck(deadLine) {  
                asyncBytes.task.cancel()
                print("trying to cancel...")
            } 
            //Wrong type of task! Should not work. if Task.isCancelled { print ("cancelled") }
            data.append(byte) 
            //just to reduce the amount of printing
            if data.count % 100 == 0 {
                print(data.count) 
            }              
        }
    }
```

If you point the URL at "https://example.com/large_file.zip" like your example and make the time interval very short the function will print "trying to cancel..." between the time your marker hits and the file completes. <strike>It does NOT however, ever print "cancelled".</strike> (The task being cancelled is a `URLSessionDataTask`, not a Swift concurrency `Task`, that line never would have worked.)

<strike>If you point either what you wrote or this function at a Server-Sent-Event stream it will cancel out just fine.</strike> (While true, its not in contrast to the other behavior, which also works just fine. There are just bigger pauses in SSE data.)

<strike>If that isn't what you want, if you want to be able to start-stop streams mid-chunk, maybe explore a custom delegate (something I haven't done yet myself), or go work with `AVFoundation` if that's an option because they've thought a lot about working with large streaming files.  I did not check making my own session and running `session.invalidateAndCancel()` on it instead, because that seems kind of extreme, but may be the way to go if you want to flush the buffer immediately.</strike>

The below will work to stop caring about the buffer immediately. It involves making a custom iterator.   <strike>but it seems kind of quirky and may not in fact arrest the downloading (still cost users data rates and power). I haven't looked into how the stream protocol relates to the network protocol on that lower level, if you stop asking does it stop getting? I don't know.</strike>  The cancel will arrest the stream allowing through the bytes that are already in the buffer, but your code won't get them. On my todo-list now is to look into how to change buffering policies.

Rob's code seems a nice way to go and advantage of a concurrency `Task`.

```swift
    func test_customIterator(timeOut:TimeInterval, url:URL, session:URLSession) async throws {
             
        let (asyncBytes, _) = try await session.bytes(from: url)
    
        let deadLine = Date.now + timeOut
        var data = Data()
    
       func someConditionCheck(_ deadline:Date) -> Bool {
            Date.now > deadLine
        }
    
        //could also be asyncBytes.lines.makeAsyncIterator(), etc.
        var iterator = asyncBytes.makeAsyncIterator()
        while !someConditionCheck(deadLine) {
            //await Task.yield()
            let byte = try await iterator.next()
            data.append(byte!) 
            print(data.count)            
        }
        //make sure to still tell URLSession you aren't listening anymore.
        //It may auto-close but that's not how I roll.
        asyncBytes.task.cancel()
    
    }

    let tap_out:TimeInterval = 0.0005
    try await test_customIterator(timeOut: tap_out, url: URL(string:"https://example.com/large_file.zip")!, session: URLSession.shared)
```

<strike>Interesting flavor of behavior. Thanks for pointing it out. Also I didn't know that the task was already available (asyncBytes.task). Thanks for that.</strike> Incorrect. The asyncBytes.task is a `URLSessionDataTask` not a concurrency `Task`

UPDATED TO ADD:

To get part of the file explicitly

```swift
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests
    func requestInChunks(data:inout Data, url:URL, session:URLSession, offset:Int, length:Int) async throws {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("bytes=\(offset)-\(offset + length - 1)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Range")
    
        let (asyncBytes, response) = try await
            session.bytes(for: urlRequest, delegate: nil)
    
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 206 else { //NOT 200!!
            throw APIngError("The server responded with an error.")
        }
        
        for try await byte in asyncBytes { 
            data.append(byte) 
            if data.count % 100 == 0 {
                print(data.count) 
            }  
        }
    }
```

Still think if my task on hand was about file downloading `session.download` would be my go to, but then there is file clean up, etc. so I get why not go there.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate. I'm not all that familiar with `Tasks` yet, so I'm not sure if testing for `isCancelled` like in your example, should work. I checked for `asyncBytes.task.isCancelled` and it *did* say that it was appropriately cancelled.

Comment: In the end, what I've gone with is using a `URLSessionDownloadTask` – which can be properly cancelled – and the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` to get notified of the bytes written. Not very fancy, but does the trick as you would expect.

Comment: Sometimes you can't beat known-working for sure! I'm not on an explicit deadline so I'm still going to monkey around with this a bit more. I'll update with what I find.